# Custom View inside a custom ViewGroup. Clicks on the View don't propagate to parent ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-custom-view, touch-event

I've a `ViewGoroup` that contains a custom control coded by me, a progress wheel that extends `View`.

The progress wheel does not have code to manage click or touch.

The container (it's a `ViewGroup`) has a touch manager:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (isValueSettable()) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ...
            return true;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            return true;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Ok?

If I click on the `ViewGroup` outside the area covered by the inner progress wheel the event is raised and I enter in `onTouchEvent()`, but I I flick inside the area of the progress wheel... nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the king of *self-learned* badge. Again, I found a solution to my own question: simply add the attribute

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

to the inner view.